# Given two solutions, find the solution of $y'=A(t)y, y(0) = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Let $A(t)$ a matrix such that
> $\phi_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
>   t+2 \\
>   t^2-1
> \end{pmatrix}$
> and $\phi_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
>   t+1 \\
>   t^2
> \end{pmatrix}$ are the solutions of the equation $y'=A(t)y$.
>
> Solve the Cauchy problem $y'=A(t)y$, $y(0) = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Here is what I have so far:

$A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c& d\end{pmatrix}$ and so we have the following systems:

$a(t+2)+b(t^2-1)=1$

$a(t+1)+b(t^2)=1$

And

$c(t+2)+d(t^2-1)=2t$

$c(t+1)+d(t^2)=2t$

And so $A(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac 1{t^2+t+1} & \frac 1{t^2+t+1}\\\frac {2t}{t^2+t+1}& \frac {2t}{t^2+t+1}\end{pmatrix}$...right?

Now I'm trying to solve $y'=A(t)y$. We get that $y_2'=2ty_1'$. And this is where I'm stuck... How do I continue from here? Also I feel like I'm overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to get $A$. Since $\phi_1(t)$ and $\phi_2(t)$ are linearly independent, one has the fundamental matrix
$$ Y(t)=(\phi_1(t),\phi_2(t))=\left(\begin{matrix}t+2&t+1\\
t^2-1&t^2\end{matrix}\right). $$
So the general solution is
$$ y(t)=Y(t)\binom{c_1}{c_2}. $$
Using the initial condition $y(0)=\binom{0}{1}$, one has $c_1=-1,c_2=2$. So
$$ y(t)=\binom{t}{t^2+1}. $$